# How to have Keras model do early-stopping in different fit calls

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Since the data dimension is big for my task, 32 samples would consume nearly 9% of memory in server, of which total free memory is about 105G. So I have to do consecutive calls to fit() in the loop. And I also want to do early-stopping with the consecutive calls to fit().

However, since the callback methods introduced in Keras documents only apply to one single fit() call.

How can I do early-stopping in this case?

Following is my code snippet:

```
for sen_batch, cls_batch in train_data_gen:

    sen_batch = np.array(sen_batch).reshape(-1, WORD_LENGTH, 50, 1)
    cls_batch = np.array(cls_batch)

    model.fit(x = sen_batch,y = cls_batch)

    num_iterations += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use [`fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator): as you have generator - you could use generator traning instead of classical `fit`. This method supports `Callbacks` so you could use [`keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping).
2. When you cannot use `fit_generator`:
   So - first of all - you need to use [`train_on_batch`](https://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch) method - as `fit` call resets many model states (e.g. optimizer states).

   `train_on_batch` method returns a loss value, but it doesn't accept callbacks. So you need to implement `early stopping` on your own. You can do it e.g. like this:

   ```
   from six import next

   patience = 4
   best_loss = 1e6
   rounds_without_improvement = 0

   for epoch_nb in range(nb_of_epochs):
       losses_list = list()
       for batch in range(nb_of_batches):
           x, y = next(train_data_gen)
           losses_list.append(model.train_on_batch(x, y))
       mean_loss = sum(losses_list) / len(losses_list)

       if mean_loss < best_loss:
           best_loss = mean_loss
           rounds_witout_improvement = 0
       else:
           rounds_without_improvement +=1

       if rounds_without_improvement == patience:
           break
   ```